# How to configure arara to post process .Rnw files in statet / Eclipse

Tags: r, eclipse, knitr, tex, statet

I would like to use [arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara) to post process the .tex files produced from Sweave (.Rnw) documents in R, and use it to build glossaries or bibliographies in reports. How do you integrate that in the [statet](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) eclipse plugins ?

The arara header is put on top of the .Rmd file and will be processed to the .tex file as following.

```
% arara: pdflatex:  { action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
% !arara: bibtex
% arara: makeglossaries
% !arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
% !arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{salmon}{name={salmon},description={Anadromous migratory fish}}
\newglossaryentry{eel}{name={eel},description={Catadromous fish of the genus
anguilla}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
An example for \gls{salmon} and \gls{eel}
\printglossary[numberedsection]
\end{document}
```

This way I will be able to run the bibtex and makeglossaries command. Now I want to integrate that command into the statet IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Congigure Arara for eclipse.

Go to the tool button (see below)> external tool configuration

[image]

Then click on program > new 
[image]

And configure arara as following :

[image]

Then create an example code. You .Rnw file or latex file must have the first lines with `% arara:` and commands. Below I'm using first *pdflatex* to build the file then *bibtex* and *makeglossary*, finally I re-run the *pdflatex* twice for a complete document. You can avoid one step simply by typing `!arara:`.

Here is an example which uses both `\gls{}`commands for glossary and `\cite{}` commands for bibtex. The R code is just to show that this is a .Rnw document.

> ```
> % arara: pdflatex:  { action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
> % arara: bibtex
> % arara: makeglossaries
> % arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
> % arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
> ```

***arara.Rnw :***

```
% arara: pdflatex:  { action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
% arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode, synctex: True }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{knitr}{name={Knitr},description={A package for reproducible
research}} 
\newglossaryentry{latex}{name={Latex},description={A typesetting program}}
\newglossaryentry{arara}{name={Arara},description={TeX automation tool based on
rules and directives.}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

<<get_citation, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE >>=
print(citation("knitr"),bibtex=TRUE)
@

This short reproducible example demonstrates how to use the \gls{arara}
\gls{latex} tool with a \textbf{Sweave} document, using eclipse and \gls{knitr}. 
For demonstration we will  include a bibliography using \cite{knitr_2017} and
\cite{knitr_2015}.

\printglossary[numberedsection]
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{arara}
\end{document}
```

***arara.bib :***

```
@Book{knitr_2015,
    title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
    author = {Yihui Xie},
    publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
    address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
    year = {2015},
    edition = {2nd},
    note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
    url = {https://yihui.name/knitr/},
  }  

@Manual{knitr_2017,
    title = {knitr: A General-Purpose Package for Dynamic Report Generation in R},
    author = {Yihui Xie},
    year = {2017},
    note = {R package version 1.17},
    url = {https://yihui.name/knitr/},
  }
```

When first running the .Rmd, the bibliography and glossaries are not built.

[image]

So what you do is you shift the the ***LATEX*** file and click on the cmd button arara

[image]

finally you get the document built with the bibliography and glossaries, re-run the arara process if you need to update the bibliography and glossaries, otherwise just run the knitr command, the pdf will be built.

[image]